# how to use javascript regex, get first word and last word from html

Tags: javascript, regex

javascript how to preg match first word and last word from html?

for example, in the below sentence, I want get words `The` and `underway`. Thanks.

```
<p>The Stack Overflow 2011 community moderator election is underway</p>
//should consider the different html tags.
```

Comment: Don't use regexes on html. Use DOM operations. Once you've extracted a string from HTML, then it's acceptable... but not on raw html.

Comment: wow - you're just asking for disappointment to only use JavaScript and regex... are you open to using / able to use jQuery or a similar library?

Comment: What is your current approach/solution and what exactly isn't working as intended?

Comment: also - assuming you've gotten rid of the nesting SGML stuff, what would happen if there's only one word in an string? both return the same? or which one is to be empty?

Comment: @CodeJockey: why is he asking for disappointment to only use JavaScript and regex?  You don't need libraries for simple stuff like this.

Comment: @AndyE My statement was based on assumptions of actual practical use. There are many things (some you point out in your answer) that will cause trouble, and would be more easily resolved with various tools (jQuery, et al. could most likely be avoided) handling punctuation would be a good use for regex, handling sub-tags (like `<em>` would be handled somewhat by using `innerText` or the like, rather than `innerHTML`) - it's more complicated than just the example in the question - but if it works for him, good for both of you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the element is already in the document, you can get its text content and split it based on `" "`:

```
var text  = "textContent" in document.body ? "textContent" : "innerText",
    el    = document.getElementById("myElement"),
    arr   = el[text].split(" "),
    first = arr.shift(),
    last  = arr.pop();

alert("1st word is '"+first+"', last word is '"+last+"'.");
```

If it's not already an element, make it one:

```
var arr, first, last,
    text  = "textContent" in document.body ? "textContent" : "innerText",
    html = "<p>The Stack Overflow 2011 community moderator election is underway</p>",
    el   = document.createElement("div");

el.innerHTML = html;
arr   = el[text].split(" "),
first = arr.shift(),
last  = arr.pop();

alert("1st word is '"+first+"', last word is '"+last+"'.");
```

Note: this doesn't take punctuation characters into account - you might want to remove some of them from the string with a simple regex before splitting.  Also, if there is only a single word in the text, `last` will be `undefined`.  If there are no words, 1st will be an empty string, `""` and last will still be `undefined`.

Comment: May be I have not description my question clear, but this is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: per my comment on the question, have you considered using `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`? it would eliminate certain nastiness that might crop up, while hopefully giving closer-to-expected results (in most cases)

Comment: @CodeJockey: this answer does use `innerText`/`textContent` when extracting the words.  It only uses `innerHTML` for the purposes of removing the tags.

Comment: I am not completely familiar with that construct (and the algorithm you put it in obfuscates it slightly as well), but I think I see how it works now - my bad! and thanks for the JavaScript lesson (that is assuming it's valid ~_^ )

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regular expressions:

```
var words = "The Stack Overflow 2011 community moderator election is underway".split(" "),
    first = words[0],
    last = words[words.length-1];
```